# Usage of current_timestamp() in IF function in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Am not able to use current_timestamp() inside IF function in mysql. Why is it so?
IS there any method to surpas it?

In microsoft excel we can use Today() inside IF().any similar thing in mysql?

Comment: Pleas publish the IF function you tried..

Comment: I have a column called entry_date(date when a particular entry is made). I want a generated column 'status' which shows either 'ripe' or 'unripe' after a particular timespan. So for that i made a generated column with following query "alter table product add column status varchar(11) generated always as (IF(Current_timestamp>=entry_date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR,"RIPE","UNRIPE")) STORED; ". WHEN i try to run it,it says current_timestamp() not allowed in IF.any alternative suggestion ?

Comment: Non deterministic functions are not allowed in generated columns consider not holding a column which can be easily calculated or running an event periodically to update a status column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with using current_timestamp() in an if function for example

```
select current_timestamp(),
        if(1 = 1 , current_timestamp(),null);
```

produces

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| current_timestamp() | if(1 = 1 , current_timestamp(),null) |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 2020-07-08 12:29:29 | 2020-07-08 12:29:29                  |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use now(), curdate(). What actually do you want to do?

Comment: I have a column called entry_date(date when a particular entry is made). I want a generated column 'status' which shows either 'ripe' or 'unripe' after a particular timespan. So for that i made a generated column with following query "alter table product add column status varchar(11) generated always as (IF(Current_timestamp>=entry_date + INTERVAL 24 HOUR,"RIPE","UNRIPE")) STORED; ". WHEN i try to run it,it says current_timestamp() not allowed in IF.any alternative suggestion ?

Comment: Then make sure your column is a timestamp field